# Having trouble compiling UnrealScript with defaultproperties

Tags: udk, scripting

Have just started scripting in Unreal Script and am following the instructions of the opening chapter of a book on the subject. I have set the development tools up as described in the book such that it is now possible to compile the scripts for UDK before adding them to a level. My issue is: the very first script the book asks you to compile is the following:

```
class AwesomeActor extends Actor
placeable;

defaultproperties
{
    Begin Object Class=SpriteComponent Name = Sprite
        Sprite = Texture2D'EditorResources.S_NavP'
    End Object
    Components.Add(Sprite)

}
```

And when I hit F9 in the compiler I get the following error message: Error, BEGIN OBJECT: Must specify valid name for suboject/copmponent: Begin Object class=SpriteComponent name = Sprite

My question: As far as I'm aware I've copied the code from the book veribatim including capital and smaller case letters but I'm getting this error and I was wondering if anyone knew why and if so how I would fix it?

Comment: Is your package compiling before Core? It needs to be set to compile after all the other packages.

Comment: Yes the script is compiling after the others but I've got it working now - its either a syntax problem in that you can't apparently have spaces between words and equal signs in UnrealScript or the version of UDK I was originally using (Feb 2013) has stricter syntax requirments. Either way I've downloaded the Nov 2012 version and removed the gaps in the code between the words and equal signs - that did it. Apparently not veribatim after all.

Comment: Ah! Yeah, the script compiler's handling of whitespace in the defaultproperties block has always been pretty spotty. Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, the issue was syntax-related, as the white space between the operators  and operands was causing parsing issues. To quote the official documentation for UnrealScript:

> As mentioned previously, the rules of the defaultproperties block is
>   slightly different from the standard unrealscript syntax. The general
>   differences are:
>
> ...
>
> Spaces should be avoided (such as between variable name, assignment operator,
>   and value).

https://udn.epicgames.com/Three/UnrealScriptDefaultProperties.html